# Boolean True or False

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = false;
        b = true;

        boolean toBe = false;
        b = toBe || !toBe;
        if (b) {
            System.out.println(toBe);
        }



    }
```

I saw this code online while trying to learn boolean and the output of this is false. Can someone please explain to me how why is the output false? Thank you

Comment: Because `toBe` is false.

Comment: What do you expect it to output and why?

Comment: `b` is true (`toBe || !toBe`) and `toBe` is false.  That's all there is, you never change the value of `toBe` so it has to be false.

Comment: You have `boolean toBe = false;` and then you print `toBe`

Comment: @QBrute I think OP is asking why `b` is true, and thus why the `if` statement is executed. I could be wrong though

Comment: No matter the value of `toBe`, with a `||` if you set and element and its opposite, it's mandatory that one values `true` and return true

Comment: Did you try stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You set "b" to false and then changed it to true, so "b" is true. Then you set "toBe" to false. The next line does nothing, it returns true but doesn't assign it to anything. Then you check if "b" equals true, and it does. So then you print out "toBe" which equals false. That is why false is printed.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

`||` is the logical or operator. It returns true if at least one operator is true. It's truth table looks like this:

```
a b a || b
1 1   1
1 0   1
0 1   1
0 0   0
```

Which means that b will be true, and thus the block within the if statement will execute. And it outputs "false" since that's the value of `toBe`.

Answer (score 0):

since `boolean toBe = false;`

```
b=toBe || !toBe 
b = false || !fasle
b = false || true 
b = true
```

so b is true which means

```
System.out.println(toBe); // prints false since tobBE is false
```

PLEASE: see truth table for short circuit logical or `||`

```
True || x = True
false || True = True
false || Flase = false
```

`x ->`  is a don't care i.e either  `true` or `false`